# How often animals are respawned in oases?

Tags: travian

I'm curious about those:

- What is minimum time needed for it?
- How long it takes for a full respawn?

Answer (score -1):

I know only rats:
rats spawns at rate 1 rat per 5 minutes.

So when you attack oase right at 10:00:00
at 10:05:00 appears first rat...
at 10:25:00 appears 5th rat...

edit: Now I know also spiders.
Spiders spawns at rate 1 spider per 6 minutes.